# "The young" means young people, but are they "the modern young"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Please answer my following question.

I think that "the+'adjective'" means "*adjective* people". For example, the young means young people.

Then, I have a question. Can I use two or more adjectives in the same situation?

For instance, does "the modern young" mean "young people in modern times"?  Is it a correct grammatical usage?

Comment: I would say no. I can't give a grammatical reason. I can only say as a native speaker that it 'sounds wrong'.

Comment: I think (depending on the context of a full sentence), "modern young" could be fairly readily understood to mean today's young people.

Comment: Young Moderns was a set phrase in the 1960s.  Modern Youth would sound better than "the modern young," but "the modern young" wouldn't be wrong.  We often hear of the new rich or the far right.

Comment: We'd be more likely to refer to "the young today" instead of "the modern young"; don't ask me why, it just feels more felicitous.

Comment: To reiterate what the other people said, it sounds awkward. You could always try "the modern youth", which to me sounds better.

Comment: I understand well thanks to your kind answers. And,thank you,Rathony for editting my comment.

Comment: @Kyusakuyumeno My pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

The [Internet Grammar of English](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/nominal.htm), in its article on **nominal adjectives**, blithely says:

> they can be modified by adjectives
>
> (the gallant French
>
> the unfortunate poor)
>
> [the idle rich]

but, in line with comments above, I think that examples that don't sound at least faintly ridiculous (probably because pairing adjective with adjective-as-noun is incongruous) are few and far between. 'The modern young' sounds tongue-in-cheek at best.

This is probably less of a problem with nationalities, where the 'nouniness' of say *the British*, *the Japanese* is perhaps more firmly established. There is also the snowclone of the form 'blue is the new grey'.