# Using the definite article before adjectives

Tags: adjectives, definite-articles

It is usual to use the definite article "the" before an adjective referring to a certain group of people. My question is: can we rewrite the following sentence without "the"?

- The current economic crisis is affecting both ***the*** poor and ***the*** rich.

Comment: Duplicate? ["...\[b\]etween rich and poor" and "...\[b\]etween the rich and the poor"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/467469/191178)

Comment: @Laurel: You'r right. Same question. I should have searched in the website before posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Here are some examples from the literature.

- ([ref. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Faith_and_Wealth/cMNKAwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22both+poor+and+rich%22&pg=PA208&printsec=frontcover) ) Let us therefore, both poor and rich, cease from taking the property of others. For my present discourse is not only to the rich, but to the poor also. For they too rob those that are poorer than themselves.
- ([ref. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Love_Does_Not_Seek_Its_Own/dOgbEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22both+poor+and+rich%22&pg=PT162&printsec=frontcover)) Therefore, rich and poor have not only met each other; they have been given to each other. If traveling the road of life alone, both poor and rich face insurmountable challenges:
- ([ref. 3](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Poverty_and_Underdevelopment_in_Tribal_A/uwTr9rh2LXQC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22both+poor+and+rich%22&pg=PA281&printsec=frontcover)) *Second year of drought* Both poor and rich start suffering . Poor farmers suffer more than rich farmers do and so they start outmigrating first .

There are many more examples on [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22both%20poor%20and%20rich%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).